# Moveing a Robot

Tags: control, ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
How to move a Robot(In my case its Pioneer lx) from its source to goal position using moveit in ROS Kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260755/moveing-a-robot/) by [Gaurav](https://answers.ros.org/users/30216/gaurav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must first setup your robot. Follow: [setup assistant tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html)

Then, you can use Rviz([tutorial for rviz plugin](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ros_visualization/visualization_tutorial.html)) to plan or create a node with moveit_ros_interface in C++ ([c++ moveit interface](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html)) or python [python moveit interface](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html)).

---

Originally posted by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) with karma: 114 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0